# KeyUp event with Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need help in using keyup with `@Html.TextBoxFor`. I have a html code which creates a new row of texboxes on each button click. Now i want to convert the text entered into that textbox into upper case while the user enters. Thought of using `OnKeyUp` event, but need help in syntax with `@Html.TextBoxFor` . I'm new to .Net. Here's my html code line

```
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(x =>x.ItemName[0].SerialNumber, new {autocomplete = "off"}) </div>
```

Help me with the JS also please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `OnKeyUp` attribute to your textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x =>x.ItemName[0].SerialNumber, new {autocomplete = "off", onkeyup="ToUpper(this);"})
```

On the script side, you need to have `ToUpper` method also like this:

```
<script>
    function ToUpper(obj)
    {
        if (obj.value!="")
        {
            obj.value = obj.value.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This worked for me, but this is working only for first row of textbox. When i tried to add more rows by clicking button(there's button to add more rows of textboxes dynamically) it's not working for newly created rows.

Comment: How do you create new rows?

Comment: So, there's a button in my. html page called "Add More Rows". By clicking on that button, one more row of textbox is created and the id of that textbox is becoming ItemName[1].SerialNumber. Now if i type anything in this new textbox, its not converting to upper case. Sorry that i couldn't post the code. I hope u got my point.

Comment: It's hard to understand from that, could you please add your related code to question?

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I got it resolved. Just went through the code on how extra rows are being added and i added onkeyup attribute there as u said and it worked. Thanks alot